# Why in the definition of $\mathcal{C}_0 (K)$ do we suppose that $K$ is a locally compact topological space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a locally compact topological space. As usual, $\mathcal{C}(K)$ denotes the space of all real continuous mappings defined on $K$, endowed with the supremum norm and
$$\mathcal{C}_0 (K)=\{ f\in \mathcal{C}(K)\; :\; \forall \varepsilon >0, \; \text{the set}\; \{ t\in K\; :\;  |f(t)|\geq \varepsilon \} \; \text{is compact} \} .$$

Why ,in the definition, do we suppose that  $K$ is a locally compact topological space? If $K$ is not a locally compact topological space, then $\mathcal{C}_0 (K)$ is still normed space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we also require the Hausdorff axiom. If $K$ is not locally compact, then you can still consider $C_0(K)$ which is a non-unital commutative $C^*$-algebra. By Gelfand duality however, $C_0(K) \cong C_0(K')$ (as $C^*$-algebras, and thus also as Banach spaces) where $K'$ is some locally compact Hausdorff space (more precisely, we can take $K'$ to be the non-zero multiplicative functionals on $C_0(K)$ endowed with the relative weak$^*$-topology) so you don't gain anything by omitting the assumption that $K$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.